# what could be wrong with this uml relationships

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Hi I am trying to create class diagrams, but I am not sure enough that my opinion is good, could you tell me what should I change, thanks.

dont sure also maybe association?
[image]

[image]

maybe association?

[image]

Comment: Do you get a diagram ? because like that this is not clear.

Comment: So new we get the schema and a question, but what is your context and the purpose of the schema ? Without them it could be very good or very bad :) By the way all attributes are public: this is not usual.

Comment: All atributes are public because I use this classes in passenger_train class (to get access to all fields of the classes)

Comment: Goodness! What should that be? Are you talking about trains or networks? A `passager_train` composed of `passenger`s? Are they operated by pedals the passengers must turn?

Comment: I write this topic to get your ideas (if train was destroyed, the passengers also were destroyed(like passengers not like people))

Comment: @mark blacksmith, a model ... design something for a purpose, without purpose : you can do what you want. So you give your try: good, your question 'is right' ? (bad question anyway, saying that you have no idea) but what is the problem ? What you said about public it's just a bad practice. Could you look on the net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question, although as the commenters are trying to explain to you you haven't asked it clearly. I believe you are asking what type of association you should use between your classes.

The composition association, as you appear to partially understand, means that the lifetime of an object in a composition relationship depends on the object of which it is a part.

Your first diagram, then, is saying that your train is composed of train stops, and that therefore if there were no train, there would no longer be any train stops. This is obviously not true; other trains could stop at the same stops. Furthermore, your train is probably going to associate with a "route" object, which will be an aggregate of a number of stops. I'll leave you to work out the details of that.

Your next diagram is saying that a train is composed (at least in part) of passengers, so that if the train is destroyed, there are no more passengers. But a passenger can switch trains and continue to be a passenger, so you don't have a composition relationship between train and passenger. The passenger rides trains, the train may or may not have passengers, so you have a simple association (no diamond of any kind).

Finally, your last diagram is saying that available routes are composed of cities. This is plausible. However, there is also the issue that a given city may be a member of different routes. If so, it may be better to say that a given city "has" a number of routes associated with it. In such a case, there would be a white diamond on the city end. Of course, if you do that, you're going to have to rethink your `distance_between` attribute. It might be best to create a `distance` class, which itself is associated with two and only two city objects.

Comment: Bob, I agree mostly with your answer, but there is one detail that I think is not entirely correct. It is not because a passenger can switch trains, or even exist without a train, that it shouldn't be a composition. Not that I'm saying it should, only that that should not be the reason for not using a composition. In the classic case of car-wheel I can move a wheel from one car to the next, and I can also detach a wheel and store in somewhere else without a car.

Comment: @GeertBellekens As I understand the car-wheel example, it's a matter of context. Car and wheel might be composition in a car factory and aggregation in a junkyard or service department. While it is of course true that the wheel can exist in physical reality independently of the car, in a car factory it might make business sense for a logical wheel to not exist independently of a car in some context of process. That of course would be less likely in a junkyard context. All that said, what *do* you think is the reason that the train-passenger association shouldn't be composition?

Comment: Two reasons I guess. 1. I don't see a semantic **whole-part** relation between train and passenger. A train is related to a number of passengers, but I would never say that a train "is composed of" passengers. 2. Depending on how you model it, a passenger may take multiple train rides, so he would be part of multiple trains, which is in violation of the rules for a compositions (there can at maximum be one whole.)